# Make CKEditor visible with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Hi usually i find answer of my every question here but this time i have to ask one... ;)

I am working on a web page and I want to make a text editable with ckeditor and what i have achieved till now is when you go on the text and click on it ckeditor will appear and you can edit the text.
But Now I want that is on clicking a button(showing small pencil) which I placed on the top of text should ckeditor appear to edit that text.

I am new to Javascript so really need your help.
Would appreciate it :)

HTML Code:

```
echo ("<hr><h4>" . PROCESS_VIEW_DESCRIPTION . "</h4><button id=\"edit_img\"><img src=\"../data/image/button/edit_page.png\"/></button>
            <div class=\"full editable\">
            <p>" HERE IS THIS LONG TEXT "</p>
            </div>");
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
$('.editable').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id == undefined || id == ''){
        id = 'content_'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999);
        $(this).attr('id',id);
    }

    // default
    $('#'+id+'.editable:not(.simple,.full)').ckeip({
        e_url: $(this).data('handler'), // action file which handle $_POST['content']
        e_hover_color: '#ffa07a',
        ckeditor_config : {
            width:'100%',
            toolbar:
            [
                ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript'],
                ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
                ['TextColor','BGColor' ],
                ['RemoveFormat' ],'/',
                [ 'Format','Font','FontSize' ],
                ['Outdent','Indent'],
                [ 'Link','Unlink','-','ShowBlocks'],'/',
                ['NewPage'],
                ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar' ],
                ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'],
                ['Undo','Redo','-','Source','-','Maximize']
            ],
        }
    });

    $('#'+id+'.full.editable').ckeip({
        e_url: $(this).data('handler'), // action file which handle $_POST['content']
        ckeditor_config : {
            width:'100%'

        }
    });

    $('#'+id+'.simple.editable').ckeip({
        e_url: $(this).data('handler'), // action file which handle $_POST['content']
        ckeditor_config : {
            width:'100%',
            toolbar:
            [
                ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
                ['Maximize']
            ]
        }
    });

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys i solved it. It was easier than i thoght. I dont need any extra javascript function i just used onclick function in button `<div  class="full editable" id="DivToedit">
<p>" TEXT TO EDIT"</p></div>");`
`<input onclick=\"$('#DivToedit').click();\" type=\"button\" name=\"button\"  class=\"editText\" value=\"DivToEdit\">`  anyways Thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the entire thing in a div and `hide/show` that

```
<div class="hideableTextEditor" style="display: none">
    // CKEditor
</div>


$("#edit_img").click(function(){
    $(".hideableTextEditor").show();
});
```

Comment: thanx for the reply .......                                                  I tried this but it hides the text i want to edit and when i click on the button..the text appears.. thats not what i want

Comment: I could help you, if you showed me what you are talking about. Make a JSFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzBrL/               Here is JSFiddle Now i want to edit that text with ck editor when the button is clicked

Comment: I can edit that text with ck editor by clicking on it..on jsfiddle its not working due to missing ckeditor.js file...but my aim is to edit that text by clicking on the button and not on the text...i hope JSFiddle makes you clear what i want :)

Comment: As far as I can see you just need to show the div that prepends your text. Without a working example I can't show you, but it already contains the code: `$('#ckeip_' + u_id + '').show();`

Answer (score 0):

evtl eine Lösung
Dem div eine ID geben. Im Button die id z.b. im valuetag verstecken

Mit dem Button Click übergibst du dann die ID von dem div welches du bearbeiten willst.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="editText" name="button" value="DivToEdit">
<div class=\"full editable\" id="DivToEdit">
    <p>" HERE IS THIS LONG TEXT "</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
....
$('.editText').each(function() {
    $(this).click( function() { 
         var idToEdit = $(this).val();

         ....

     });
});
...
```

Comment: kommt dieser javascriptcode  mit dem vorhandenen code den ich gepostet habe!?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example
HTML code

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="show">
<input type="button" value="Done" id="hide"><br/>
<div id="txt">text to edit</div><br/>
<textarea id="txtarea"> </textarea>
```

Javascript Code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#txtarea').hide();
});

$( "#show" ).click(function() {
    var value=$("#txt").text();
    $( "#txtarea" ).val(value);
    $('#txtarea').show();
    $('#txt').hide();
});
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
    var value=$( "#txtarea" ).val();
    $( "#txt").html(value);
    $('#txt').show();
    $('#txtarea').hide();
});
```

for your web application replace the textarea with CKEditor.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32tFh/)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Because CKEditor will produce HTML code. To render it in your page, so we need to use `$( "#txt").html(value);`.

Comment: Hi thanx...its working with texteditor but doesnt working with ckeditor...:/    and i dont need that done button because ckeditor has already two buttons "save" and "cancel"

Comment: "for your web application replace the textarea with CKEditor"  What do you mean by that? simply change the id="editable" which is for ckeditor!? if i am not wrong!?